# How to disable expansion of percent sign('%') in cmdline and `:exec`?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, cmdline

Besides type in cmdline directly, I also use

```
vnoremap <F2> :<c-u>exec join(getline("'<","'>"),"\n")<CR>
nnoremap <F2> :exec getline(".")<CR>
nnoremap <F3> :.w !sed 's/\r$// ; s/^\s*\$\s*\(.*\)\s*/\1/' \|bash -o pipefail<CR>
```

to run vim/shell command in current buffer. eg,

- `<F2>` to run current line as vim command.
- `<F3>` to run current line as shell command.
- `4<F3>` to run curent line and 3 lines below it as shell command.

So how can I disable expansion of `%`,

- at cmdline, eg `:!awk 'BEGIN { print 4 % 3} '`
- `exec` + `getline()`

Comment: simply escape it :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did, escaping them, either individually, or `s/%/\\%/g` when multiple ones.

Answer (score 5):

`escape(getline('.'), '%')`

See `:h escape()` for more information

Comment: See also `shellescape()`, eg, `let cmd = shellescape(join( getline(a:firstline,a:lastline), "\n"),1)`, other item that might be of interest is `v:count`, `func-range`, and `function-range-example`.